# Selenium sikuli ImageFile null not found on disk

Tags: selenium, sikuli

I am new to sikuli and selenium. While executing following pregame i am getting "FindFailed: ImageFile null not found on disk"

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class prac1 
{
@Test
public void f() throws Exception 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://rakesh//software//selenium browser//chrome 2.30//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.techved.com/career");
    driver.findElement(By.id("aplybtn1")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
    Pattern submit_btn = new Pattern(".//ele_screenshot//choose_btn.PNG");
    Pattern file_upload = new Pattern(".\\ele_screenshot\\file_upload.PNG");
    Pattern open_btn = new Pattern(".\\ele_screenshot\\open_btn.PNG");

    Screen screen = new Screen();
    screen.setAutoWaitTimeout(3);
    screen.click(submit_btn);
    screen.type(file_upload, "C:\\Users\\techved\\Desktop\\performance.txt");
    screen.click(file_upload);
    screen.click(open_btn);     
}
```

Comment: where is it erroring? can you post the stackstrace?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some issues in your code (for example inconsistently defined system paths) that I will not go into at the moment but you should check.

The error means pretty much what it says, that the image cannot me located on disk. This usually means that the `bundlePath` to a location different to that of your image files. To know what path is currently used to search for images and to set custom path, use these:

```
System.out.println(ImagePath.getBundlePath()); // print current bundlePath
ImagePath.setBundlePath("src/main/resources/images"); // set custom bundlePath

System.out.println(ImagePath.getBundlePath()); // print new bundlePath
```

You can find a bit more information [here](http://eugenesautomation.blogspot.com.au/2017/08/setting-image-path-in-sikulix.html).